# Deprecation of Google API

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-contacts-api

Can you please let me know if the following can still be used? after 4/20:
     com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic.GenericEntry;
     com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
     com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
     com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
     com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetFeed;
     com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactEntry; 
     com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactFeed;
     com.google.gdata.data.contacts.Hobby
   I believe these will work after 4/20. Can you please confirm if this needs to be replaced?  I checked my jar for contacts and it is using v3.

Answer (score 0):

Spread sheets API v3 and contacts API v3 are available and are not deprecated which are still on gdata. check this [link1](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and [link2](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).So, you can use the above libraries but you should use Oauth2 as Oauth 1 is deprecated and is not supported by Google after May 5,2015.